# How can I pull out the result from a PL/SQL table?

Tags: plsql

I created a PL/SQL table and retrieve some data from other tables and store into it. Now I want to make sure that all the data are inserted into the PL/SQL table properly. How can I pull out the result from the PL/SQL table? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the PL/SQL site for a tutorial?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "pull out"?

Comment: Because I used a procedure to populate the PL/SQL table that I created, I want to check whether table is properly populated after I execute the procedure.

Comment: Show us the stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the tables (and the query) used by the procedure to populate the destination table, you can left join them with the latter and filter the null values: if you have one or more records, the insert fails somewhere; for example:

```
Select count(1) -- if >0 the destTable is not correct
from
TableA A inner join TableB B on
 A.id=B.Id
left join destTable C on
 B.id=C.id
Where
 C.id is null;
```

Or, in the procedure, use an exception in the insert query
You should paste the code to better understand.